# it possible to disable the 'Drawer.Screen' so that it cannot be clicked (React Native)?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb9Mk.jpg)
Is it possible to disable the 'Survey Form' so it cannot be clicked?
I'm using React Navigation for drawer navigation in my React Native app. I have a Drawer.Screen component where I'm trying to disable clicks on the navigation item based on a certain condition.
I try this code

```
> <Drawer.Screen
name="SurveyForm"
component={activeSurvey === 'active' ? SurveyForm : HomePage}
options={{
headerShown: false,
drawerLabel: '- Survey Form',
drawerLabelStyle: {
color: activeSurvey === 'active' ? '#2D2D2D' : '#808080',
 },
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent going into the clicked drawer screen you can use below listener

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('drawerItemPress', (e) => {
    // Prevent default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do something manually
    // ...
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Check the react navigation document for [drawerItemPress](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#draweritempress)

You have to put that screen condition in listener and just call `e.preventDefault();` in that case